# PostgreSQL function to return a join from 2 select statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wanna create a function which generates a result from two select statements.
Please find below the query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION claims_rez_ram(calc_date date)
RETURNS TABLE (
                Serie varchar(50)
                , Numar varchar(50)
                , Claim_File_Index integer
                , Claim_File varchar(30)
                , Claim_Date date
                , Claim_Notif_Date date
                , Rez_Const_Lei double precision
                , Plata_Lei double precision
                , Rez_Ram double precision) as $func$ 

BEGIN               
--drop table if exists claims_paid
-- Plati
RETURN QUERY select
    p."PSN" 
    , p."PNR" 
    , d_p."Index" as claim_file_index
    , d_p."DAMFileNr" as claim_file
    , d_p."DAMDate" as claim_date
    , d_p."DAMAvizDate" as claim_notif_date
    , ROUND(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN d_pay."EID"='10' THEN d_pay."PAYVal"
                    ELSE d_pay."PAYVal"*exch_p."EXCValue" end) as NUMERIC),2) as plata_LEI
    , pr."Index" as index_pr
    , r."Index" as index_risk
into claims_paid
from "DAM" as d_p
JOIN "DAMPay" as d_pay on d_p."Index"=d_pay."DID"
JOIN "Pols" as p on p."Index" = d_p."PID"
JOIN "PolsRisc" as pr on d_pay."PRID" = pr."Index"
JOIN "Riscs" as r on r."Index" = pr."RID"
JOIN "EXCValues" exch_p ON exch_p."EID"=d_pay."EID"
where (d_pay."EID"='10' or exch_p."AtDate"=calc_date) and d_pay."PAYDate" <= calc_date
group by 
    p."PSN" 
    , p."PNR" 
    , d_p."Index" 
    , d_p."DAMFileNr" 
    , d_p."DAMDate"
    , d_p."DAMAvizDate" 
    , pr."Index"
    , r."Index" ;
    
--select * from claims_paid
--drop table if exists claims_paid


--Rezerve Constituite   
--drop table if exists claims_rez_const

RETURN QUERY select
    p."PSN" 
    , p."PNR" 
    , d_r."Index" as claim_file_index
    , d_r."DAMFileNr" as claim_file
    , d_r."DAMDate" as claim_date
    , d_r."DAMAvizDate" as claim_notif_date
    , ROUND(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN d_rez."EID"='10' THEN d_rez."RDAM"
                    ELSE d_rez."RDAM"*exch_r."EXCValue" end) as NUMERIC),2) as rez_const_LEI
    , pr."Index" as index_pr
    , r."Index" as index_risk
into claims_rez_const
from "DAM" as d_r
JOIN "DAMRez" as d_rez on d_r."Index"=d_rez."DID"
JOIN "Pols" as p on p."Index" = d_r."PID"
JOIN "PolsRisc" as pr on d_rez."PRID" = pr."Index"
JOIN "Riscs" as r on r."Index" = pr."RID"
JOIN "EXCValues" exch_r ON exch_r."EID"=d_rez."EID"
where (d_rez."EID"='10' or exch_r."AtDate"=calc_date) and d_rez."RDAMDate" <= calc_date
and (d_r."IsClass" = 'false' or (d_r."IsClass" = 'true' and d_r."ClassDate" >=(calc_date + interval '1 day')))
and (d_r."IsClosed" = 'false' or (d_r."IsClosed" = 'true' and d_r."ClosedDate" >=(calc_date + interval '1 day'))) 
group by 
    p."PSN" 
    , p."PNR"
    , d_r."Index" 
    , d_r."DAMFileNr" 
    , d_r."DAMDate"
    , d_r."DAMAvizDate" 
    , pr."Index"
    , r."Index" ;
    
--select * from claims_rez_const
--drop table claims_rez_const

RETURN QUERY select 
    r_c."PSN" 
    , r_c."PNR" 
    , r_c."claim_file_index"
    , r_c."claim_file"
    , r_c."claim_date"
    , r_c."claim_notif_date"
    , r_c."rez_const_lei" as rez_const_Lei
    , coalesce(r_p."plata_lei",0) as plata_Lei
    , coalesce(r_c."rez_const_lei" - coalesce(r_p."plata_lei",0),0) as rez_ram_Lei
from claims_rez_const r_c
left join claims_paid r_p on r_c."claim_file_index"=r_p."claim_file_index"
where coalesce(r_c."rez_const_lei" - coalesce(r_p."plata_lei",0),0) != 0 ;

end

$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

The function returns the query from the third select statement.

However, I get an error

SSQL Error [42P11]: ERROR: cannot open SELECT query as cursor
Where: PL/pgSQL function claims_rez_ram(date) line 6 at RETURN QUERY

I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should use the `plpgsql` language, not `sql`
2. Write `RETURN QUERY` before every `SELECT`
3. Don't forget putting a semicolon at the end of each statement
4. Read the manual :)

Comment: thanks. Seems I got an error : SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURN". I was trying  different ways

Comment: I succeed by using your suggestion. However, I got this error when I execute the function: SQL Error [42P11]: ERROR: cannot open SELECT query as cursor
  Where: PL/pgSQL function claims_rez_ram(date) line 6 at RETURN QUERY

Comment: I put in the new one (edit it). When By select * from claims_rez_ram('2020-10-31') I got the error mentioned above

Comment: @AlinT You didn't put a semicolon after `end`

Comment: but i succeed to create the function and each select works well

Comment: @AlinT I doubt that you tested them with the `INTO` clause. Remove the `INTO` and you should be fine.

Comment: thanks. there is no change on the error. I need the into clause to create the 2 tables which are joined on the third one

Comment: @AlinT That's incorrect. Do read about the `INTO` clause. I think that in your case the correct approach would be to use the `WITH` clause to prepare the two initial datasets.

Comment: I see. Do you have a suggestion in this respect (how to use with in postgre function)? thanks

Comment: @AlinT My only suggestion for you is that you should read about it. There's no way around it - you need to be at least minimally familiar with the technology that you're using. Search Google for "PostgreSQL CTE" or "PostgreSQL WITH clause" and you'll see tons of tutorials and examples. Here's one: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-cte/